# Error: Creating aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy using Terraform not changing values in the json code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating Resource policy in rest api using terraform, i gave a json policy and parameterized some values like account_id, region, vpc_id etc.

```
data "template_file" "api_gateway_private_access_policy" {
  template = file("apgi_policy_private_vpc.json.tmpl")
  vars = {
    region           = var.region
    aws_account_id   = var.aws_account_id
    api_id           = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    vpc_endpoint_id  = var.vpc_endpoint_id
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy" "example_policy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  policy      = data.template_file.api_gateway_private_access_policy.template
}
```

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:${region}:${aws_account_id}:${api_id}/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "${vpc_endpoint_id}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:${region}:${aws_account_id}:${api_id}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The json template is not able to change the region, account_id, API_id from the variables above

Comment: Are there any terraform errors? If so, please add them to the question.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is moving to the [`templatefile` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile), as `template_file` data source has been deprecated. To achieve what you want, you would need only slight changes to the code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy" "example_policy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  policy      = templatefile("${path.root}/apgi_policy_private_vpc.json.tmpl", {
    region           = var.region
    aws_account_id   = var.aws_account_id
    api_id           = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    vpc_endpoint_id  = var.vpc_endpoint_id
  })
}
```